# elasticsearch update with partial document overwrite original document

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch update with partial document overwrite the original document instead of merging it.

I thought merge will just update corresponding properties and or insert new ones. did I miss what the merge supposed to do?

This is how I did:

mappings:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "nested" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

index doc:

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "group" : "fans",
    "user" : [
      {
        "first" : "John",
        "last" :  "Doe",
        "age": 31
      },
      {
        "first" : "Foo",
        "last" :  "Bar",
        "age" : 26
       }
     ]
}
```

partial update:

```
POST my_index/my_type/1/_update
{
  "doc": {
      "group" : "fans",
        "user" : [
        {
          "first" : "Joe",
          "last" :  "Smith",
        },
        {
          "first" : "Alice",
          "last" :  "Baz"
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

the result is just new document without the `age` property.how can I preserve the properties not in the partial update?

Comment: You cannot. The arrays of values are replaced completely, in your case `user` is an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST as provided is not using the same index and type names as the original PUT.  Try `POST my_index/my_type/1/_update` instead of `POST test/type1/1/_update`.

Comment: Ah, right.  Then I have to agree with @Andrei, your update is replacing the old `user` array in the original document with the entirely new `user` array that you supplied.